# Ask permission result

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase

When I make a paid subscription and the user sees the "Ask to buy" alert, how can I know if the request has been sent or cancelled?

Need to hide the activity indicator

[image]

Comment: You should check that status of the payment using [paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransactionobserver/1506107-paymentqueue) this allows you to verify the transaction state (I think [deferred](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransactionstate/deferred) is the one you want). Check out the documentation for more details https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/offering_completing_and_restoring_in-app_purchases

Answer (score 0):

When the Ask Permission alert appears, your app is deactivated. You can detect that fact and take down your activity indicator.